# power function in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I desperately need a solution for this... I m using Blackberry JDE 5.0. In documentation it shows net.rim.device.api.util.MathUtilities.pow ( double double ) is added form 4.6. But i couldnt get pow function when i use Math.pow().

I need to get this value...float fSecondFactor=(float) (Math.pow(1+fRatePerMonth,fNumberofMonths)-1);

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this...Plzz....

Comment: as you said, MathUtilities.pow, instead of Math.pow

Comment: Thanks Max....Such a tiny mistake.... Thanks once again....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks MAX for ur support.... as you said, MathUtilities.pow, instead of Math.pow worked...

Answer (score 0):

i blogged about this a while ago- posted a link there to a good article on it
http://bryanallott.net/blog/2010/01/to-the-power-of-by-hand.html